# How to open a file for reading and writing, create it if doesn't exist yet, and if it does, then without truncating it?

Tags: python, file-io, operating-system, race-condition

- If I use `r+`, then the file won't get created if it doesn't exist.
- If I use `w+`, the file will get truncated.
- If I use `a+`, I can only append and not seek to preexisting offsets.

So it seems like it isn't possible to do this in one call to Python built-in function `open`? I will need to use multiple calls and make sure to not introduce a race condition in between?

Comment: what if you use `a`?

Comment: you would better use more than one open() statements. I had some similar issue some days ago. Combined with an if for existance check, it will do your job well

Comment: I used 2 with open() in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little low-level helper:

```
import os

def open_create(name, flags):
    return os.open(name, flags | os.O_CREAT)

with open("./testfile", 'r+', opener=open_create) as f:
    ... read/write ...
```